# How to generate tokens for murmur3Partitioner for multiple nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra Cluster with multiple datacenters and nodes

How can I generate token values for Multi-datacenter Cassandra cluster for Murmur3Partitioner?

Answer (score 0):

I found a site which generates token for Murmur3Partitioner and RandomPartitioner but only for 1 DC.

https://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/

I will update here If found a better link.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens.html

You just need to make sure that each of the nodes in the each DC have the ranges spread evenly.